# Is there a way to get deleted campaign members via the rest API?

Tags: rest-api, campaign-member

I am using the /queryAll API to get CampaignMembers and I want to get members that have been deleted. When I use the following URL I do not get ALL of the deleted campaign members. I only get deleted members where the contact or lead associated with them has been deleted. I need to get members that have been deleted by being removed from the Campaign. Is this possible?

/services/data/v35.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT Id, IsDeleted, CampaignId, LeadId, ContactId, Status, HasResponded, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, FirstRespondedDate, Name FROM CampaignMember WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0